# Login issues - Credentials do not match in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**Hi Everyone!**

I'm using **Laravel-8 with Laravel UI**. I can able to register any user that is not a problem, but when I log out & try to login again with the same user Credential then I got this error message!

**Screenshot-1:**

[image]

**Here is my Database User Table:**

[image]

**Migrations : create_users_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->string('avater')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function uploadAvater(Request $request){
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $filename = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->image->storeAs('images', $filename);
        User::find(1)->update(['avater' => $filename]);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Models-> User.php**

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
    
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'password',
        ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password',
            'remember_token',
        ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        ];
    
        public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
        {
            $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
        }
    
    
        public function getNameAttribute($name)
        {
            return ucfirst($name);
        }
    }
?>
```

Does anyone have an idea why I can't able to login in? where is the problem? thanks!

Comment: where is your login logic and why the password is in hidden array in User model?

Comment: I am using Laravel/UI, if I removed the password from an array then is that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/577188a34f7dff772d5f25bc30c0d49711c020fd/stubs/Auth/RegisterController.stub#L70) already hashes the password field when registering. So by using an Eloquent Mutator to hash the password field, you are essentially hashing it twice.

You'll have to either remove the mutator (`setPasswordAttribute` method) or edit the [`create()` method in `RegisterController`](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/577188a34f7dff772d5f25bc30c0d49711c020fd/stubs/Auth/RegisterController.stub#L70).